# How to invite a friend to a group through a link by email or messaging apps?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

So I have two users

**User 1** = BFAO9cwDUPfpujyIpsO0T8MmYQV2
**User 2** = OYZ8kmZi0TZm8lnm6ElKEMSuWu83

**User 2** is in group 1 but **User 1** is not. My problem is how do I invite **User 1** to group 1 through email, sms or messanging apps.

I have tried working with Firebase invites but I think that is just for installations, plus I don't have my app in the app store at the moment.
Also looked at Dynamic links but it seems to be more like a promotional thing rather than an inviting to a group thing. Any suggestions or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: If a user in your app is inviting *User 1* to join *Group1* then Invites and Dynamic Links are the correct products to use. If you're having trouble making them work for this purpose, then share the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for my Deep Link url what do I enter for that one? If I do not have my app in the app store yet  @FrankvanPuffelen