# How to invite a user to a group through an email invitation link?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

In my Kivy app with Firebase backend any user can create a group. Once created, an invitation link needs to be sent to other users through email to join that particular group.
I need to find a way to send that invitation link from inside my app (python).

I've searched on the internet and it seems there are unanswered questions on that:

[Invite link to different groups using Firebase Dynamics Links in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611676/invite-link-to-different-groups-using-firebase-dynamics-links-in-flutter)

[How to invite a friend to a group through a link by email or messaging apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970884/how-to-invite-a-friend-to-a-group-through-a-link-by-email-or-messaging-apps)

I personally don't think that Firebase dynamic links (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) could be the solution: I need to create dynamically inside the app different links for different groups.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated